# how to deal with FFT parameters

Tags: android, signal-processing, fft

I recorded an audio sample, and i want to apply FFT to it,,,

I did all the steps needed in order to use FFT in android such as getting the j-transform library and everything else needed...

and with in the code, i first defined the fft :

```
   DoubleFFT_1D fft = new DoubleFFT_1D(1024);
```

and inside the code, after reading the audio file( stored as PCM) ... i applied FFT on it by using the following instruction:

```
    fft.complexForward(audio_file_in_double_format);
```

Here is my question:

First of all the number (1024) used in the parameter of the fft definition, what is it based on? and what does it mean?

Does it mean that the fft will be applied on only 1024 samples?!

And what will be the output of the fft function? i know that it will give complex numbers, so is it gonna give a result double to the input??

I need help understanding how this FFT function works?!

The code is working fine with me, but i need to understand,, because i am inputting the while audio file into the FFT function which is alot bigger than 1024 samples. So is it applying FFT to its first 1024 and ignoring the rest? or what??

Comment: Why are you using the FFT? What is your purpose? I ask because your questions indicate a lack of understanding of the fundamentals.

Comment: I am using it simply because i want the frequecny components of the audio signal. Because from what i know, the FFT converts from time domain to frequency domain.

Comment: For analysis or are you trying to modify the signal to only contain some components? If the latter, consider the time domain instead of the frequency domain: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/08/why-eq-is-done-in-time-domain.html